# MimeUtility.DecodeText() returns ? characters

Tags: mime, jakarta-mail

> "=?utf-8?B?MDJf5rW35aSW5oug54K5X0ZZMTXjgrfjgrnjg4bjg6DlgZzmraLlpInm?= =?utf-8?B?m7TkvZzmpa3kuojlrppfMjAxNTA1MDdWMS5wcHR4?="

I am trying to decode the above string using MimeUtility.DecodeText method. I get the resultant string as follows:

> 02_海外拠点_FY15システム停止変���作業予定_20150507V1.pptx

I am expecting the string to be :

> 02_海外拠点_FY15システム停止変更作業予定_20150507V1.pptx